# the power and sample size of one Poisson mean test

Tags: poisson-distribution, sample-size, statistical-power

I was using the softeware PASS to calculate the sample size and power of a one Poisson mean problem.

Solve For ................................................ Power
Ha (Alternative Hypothesis).................... Ha: λ0 < λ1
Alpha....................................................... 0.025
n (Sample Size) ...................................... 12 24
λ0 (Null or Baseline) ............................... 1.0
λ1 (Alternative)........................................ 1.1 1.4 1.8 2.2 2.5

In the PASS manuscript they explained that how the power and sample size was calculated. It is based on "Guenther, William C. 1977. Sampling Inspection in Statistical Quality Control. Griffin's Statistical  Monographs. Macmillan, NY. Pages 25-29." See the scree shot below. You can also refer to the link. Can some one explain what is the rationale of this sample size method? I cannot figure it out.

[image]
https://www.ncss.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Tests_for_One_Poisson_Mean.pdf

Comment: As for why the $\chi^2$ appears in the formula, see WIkipedia's [Poisson distribution # Related distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Poisson_distribution&oldid=878179733#Related_distributions) (specifically the last bullet-point in the section)

Comment: thanks, that answers my question regarding the chi-square. But I am still a little confused about the hypothesis testing here. The example shown in the PASS manuscript was based on the H_a: \lambda >\lamba_1. What if I would like to test the H_a:\lamda<\lambda_1? how can I construct the sample size formula?